# MSAL ANDROID : MultiAccountMode issue with Logout

Tags: java, android, azure-ad-msal

I have an android native application using MSAL library to authenticate. We are facing issues to logout from application after login. While logout, it displays a screen where the already logged in email displays, tapping on that allows the user to login to the application with out a password. The application is configured as MultiAccount mode. Below is the code for logout.

```
 removeAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mMultipleAccountApp == null) {
                    return;
                }

                /**
                 * Removes the selected account and cached tokens from this app (or device, if the device is in shared mode).
                 */
                mMultipleAccountApp.removeAccount(accountList.get(accountListSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()),
                        new IMultipleAccountPublicClientApplication.RemoveAccountCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onRemoved() {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Account removed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                        .show();

                                /* Reload account asynchronously to get the up-to-date list. */
                                loadAccounts();
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onError(@NonNull MsalException exception) {
                                displayError(exception);
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
```

It always display the toast "Account removed", but it is actually not. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 1 - 12/12/2022**

@Tinjzz [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69882490/msal-force-require-password-login-with-microsoft-account-android-studio) is almost your exact scenario.

*Question Description*
"accounts are removed successfully, but when signing in again and the microsoft sign in intent is opened, the accounts can just be clicked to sign in without password"

**@Rutha answer** "This is happening because MSAL automatically refreshes your token after expiration. When user opens your app it checks if that token is already present and valid."

"you need to remove the cache as well to remove the account from the cache, find the account that need to be removed and then call `PublicClientApplication.removeAccount()`"

In a later answer, @Rutha notes "On Android we basically don't have any control on the cookies"  "If you want the user to enter the password again then you should do this: `AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithPrompt(Prompt.ForceLogin);`

**Old Response**

From the code posted, it looks like you are using an approach similar to [this site](https://www.zditect.com/code/android/enable-authentication-in-an-android-app.html) with a separate `loadAccounts()` method. "Step 5.2: Load accounts"

However, in the [MS MSAL Single and Multi-Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-multi-account#multiple-account-public-client-application) page, it notes:

"If your app is configured to use a broker, and a broker is installed on the device, the account won't be removed from the broker when you call removeAccount. Only tokens associated with your client are removed."

MS specifically recommends using "Call `getAccounts` to get a list of accounts currently known to the app."

So, the current setup may be using `loadAccounts()` per the first link, yet MS actually recommends `getAccounts` that specifically addresses only the internal MSAL token system.

Comment: Here is the loadAccount function.  private void loadAccounts() {
        if (mMultipleAccountApp == null) {
            return;
        }

        mMultipleAccountApp.getAccounts(new IPublicClientApplication.LoadAccountsCallback() {
            Override
            public void onTaskCompleted(final List<IAccount> result) {
                accountList = result;
                updateUI(accountList);
            }

            Override
            public void onError(MsalException exception) {
                displayError(exception);
            }
        });
    }